# PowerShell - get items by view

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, view

I've run into an issue whereby running the below code will only return the items within the current *page* of a view. I.e. If I have 30 items in my view, but 60 total, I will only be returned 30 items.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $($webUrl);
$list = $web.Lists.get_Item($listName);
$view = $list.Views[$viewName];
$items = $list.GetItems($view);
```

**Question:** Is there a way to query the view and get **all** items, regardless of any paging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You need to use an `SPQuery` object (based  on your `SPView`). Use the following PowerShell commands:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $($webUrl);
$list = $web.Lists.get_Item($listName);
$view = $list.Views[$viewName];
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery($view)
$spQuery.RowLimit = 0
$items = $list.GetItems($spQuery);
```